# Unable to display the data fetch from the OBD scanner

Tags: java, android, obd-ii

I am using the library from the following link https://github.com/md-sohrab-alam/android-obd-reader. I followed the same coding as the one display on the read me page but I only get an empty screen. What could be causing this issue. There is no error code in the Run tab.

Comment: More details of what hardware and car setup you’re using might help.  I suspect though that you’re trying to read engine codes, where the sample is to read head unit  (radio) data.

Comment: I'm using an ELM327. The app of the listed link, works fine. I just followed the code from the sample app to mine.